# how to recover corrupt sqlite3 database with c code

Tags: sqlite

After doing some search and experiement, I know a corrupted sqlite3 database could be recovered with sqlite3.exe in following way:

```
.mode insert
.out xxx.sql
select * from target_table;
```

My question is that I don't know how this process could be done in an application linked with sqlite3.c with C code.

With a few knowledge on sqlite3, I know the way like:

```
sqlite3_exec(*db, "select * from target_table;", NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

But following will not work:

```
sqlite3_exec(*db, ".mode insert", NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands beginning with a dot are not SQL statements and are not part of the SQLite library; they are implemented by the `sqlite3` command-line shell.

If you really want to do the same, copy that code from SQLite's `shell.c`.

---

Please note that this algorithm is not guaranteed to recover a corrupted database.
It just reads from the table without using any index, so it works only if the corruption is restricted to some index.

If it were possible to recover automatically, SQLite would already do this instead of returning an error.